# Auto generate domain classes in java (having similar features as grails domain classes)

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, spring-data

I want to auto generate my domain classes (in java). I need methods like the ones mentioned below, which are available in grails domain classes.

Example:

- findById()
- findByName()
- save()
- delete()
- update()
- read() ...etc.

I can provide meta information (about domain) through xml, hibernate config files or any other means.

Is there any framework or utility that can allow me to do that?

Comment: It may not be precisely what you're after, but the combination of JPA and Spring Data's repository abstraction is nice when Grails/GORM is not an option.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Netbeans has a [plugin from Visual Paradigm](https://netbeans.org/features/uml/) that will generate code from UML.  They might have something similar to what you want.

Comment: Here's a plugin for [JPA model code generation](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/youtube_jpa_model_code_generator), it might be similar to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring-Roo framework it adds similar methods that are there in Grails in the Entity.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/